# Rails 5 accepts_nested_attributes_for/has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

How do I create a new model containing a reference to an association (many-to-many, using `has_many :through`) which already exists?

Here are the relevant portions of the models which form the many-to-many relationship:

```
class DietaryTagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dietary_tag
  belongs_to :dietary_taggable, polymorphic: true
end

class DietaryTag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dietary_taggings

  has_many  :users,
            source: :dietary_taggable,
            source_type: "User",
            through: :dietary_taggings
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dietary_taggings, as: :dietary_taggable
  has_many :dietary_tags, through: :dietary_taggings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dietary_tags
end
```

Given an existing `DietaryTag` whose ID is 1, when trying to create a new `User` with the following, I'm presented with an error which says, `{:dietary_taggings=>["is invalid"]}`.

`User.create(email: "someone@somewhere.com", dietary_tag_ids: [1])`

I'm able to create the join model directly using for an existing user and dietary tag: `DietaryTagging.create(dietary_taggable: User.last, dietary_tag_id: 1)`. So, I'm pretty sure the issue is either with how I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` or my expectations about how/when the join instance should be created.

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is only really needed when you want to create nested records in the same request with attributes. Its not needed when you are just assigning associations with the `_ids` setters like when you are selecting items with a select. So in this case you don't need it.

Comment: `User.create(email: "someone@somewhere.com", dietary_tag_ids: [1])` should implicitly create a `DietaryTagging` record. The question is really what is triggering the validation error.

Comment: @max I _think_ the validation is being triggered by [Rails 5's new `belongs_to` behavior](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html). If I change DietaryTagging to use, `belongs_to :dietary_taggable, polymorphic: true, optional: true` everything works as expected.

Comment: Thats wierd, rails should set both associations when creating the join model impllicitly. It could be due to the polymorphic association. Does the created DietaryTagging have the correct `dietary_taggable_id` and `dietary_taggable_type`?

Comment: @max Yes, it does.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the validation generated by the association. I would just leave  `optional: true` and use `validates_presence_of :dietary_taggable_id, :dietary_taggable_type`

Comment: @max Interestingly, adding those validations results in the same error.

Comment: Just a guess, but any chance it could be related to plural/singular? I have trouble myself sometimes remembering what gets pluralized where. Any chance it should be `User.create(email: "someone@somewhere.com", dietary_tags_ids: [1])` with a plural on `dietary_tags_ids`?

Comment: @Beartech Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work. The resulting error is, `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'dietary_tags_ids' for User`

Comment: I feel like I have run into similar before but can't remember... Something about the creation seems off but I'm no expert. I know if you were passing these in params from a web form the params would be more like: `User.create(email: "someone@somewhere.com", dietary_tag_attributes: {ids:  [1]} )